# Project included or involved orconsisted of?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage

Is it correct to say "the **project included** fundraising and construction of ..."? Shall I use other synonyms of "**included**"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends whether you are listing all the things that were part of  the project:

- The project **included** X, Y, Z
  Without any further clarification, readers tend to assume this was all the project included. But this is not necessarily true.
- The project **involved**  X, Y, Z
  This might mean that X, Y, and Z were not part of the project, but the project could not be done without also doing X, Y, and Z. If this is what you mean, you could use **entailed**.  otherwise, the meaning is basically like "Included" above.
- The project **was composed of** (or **consisted of**, or **comprised**)  X, Y, Z
  These are the most likely to be construed as saying that X, Y, and Z constituted the *entire* project. If they didn't, I wouldn't use these wordings.